# MAUI iOS EntityFramework Core - database is not created in Release iOS build

Tags: entity-framework, maui, maui-ios, ios-sqlite

The app I'm working on successfully creates am SQLite DB on Android or on an iOS Simulator and populates initial data, but Release iOS build on a real device just doesn't have any data.

I'm using Entity Framework Core
Initially I was using SQLite Nuget packages. After switching to EF I cleaned things up - removed all related packages and added only those that EF pulled along with their Nuget.

I've created a context class

```
internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() 
    {
        SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();

        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Entity1> Entities1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity2> Entities2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity3> Entities3 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyDatabase.db3");

        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlite($"Filename={dbPath}");
    }
}
```

Made a base controller class

```
internal abstract class ControllerBase<T> where T : IDBItem, new()
{
    protected IMapper _mapper;

    /// <summary>
    /// Use only in case of unavoidable execution of raw sql
    /// </summary>
    protected MyDbContext GetContext() => new MyDbContext();

    public ControllerBase() 
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile<DefaultMappingProfile>();
        });
        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

DB items look like this:

```
[PrimaryKey("Id")]
public class Entity1: IDBItem
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public float SomeField { get; set; }
}
```

So whenever context get acquired from inheriting classes - there's a check that database is created. On Android this works.
on iOS in Release mode I'm not seeing any databae entries.
I do see some entries on Simulator though. That confuses me even more.
Can any1 suggest a solution please?

I've tried to clean up Nuget packages as initially I was using SQLite PCL one. Removing all SQLite and installing only EF Core and those that it pulled didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What nuget package have you installed? Are you using [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core/7.0.10#supportedframeworks-body-tab)?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite v.7.0.13,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core appears to be installed as well

Comment: Thanks for the update, this could be a potential issue, consider report it to the GitHub :https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Comment: Got it. I will put together more technical details and report it there then. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found out that the error was caused by "Attempting to JIT compile method InitializeComponent while running in aot-only mode"
It happened only in release mode on the device.
The issue was caused by absence if tag `<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>` inside of the project file. Eventually it looked like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  [other option shere]
  <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
  <MtouchUseLlvm>False</MtouchUseLlvm>
  <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Link to the original issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17194

Comment: 1. Super, so the solution is to add `<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>` to the csproj file. 2. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.